# Firefox is not reading IIS Virtual Paths properly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox, iis

In our current project we have two virtual paths set up, one for images and one for file uploads. The virtual paths pull the images and files from a separate server. I am currently working with cross-browser compatibility and Firefox seems to be reading the virtual paths differently than all other browsers. It seems like its not be rendering the URL properly. They work fine in Chrome, Safari, and in IE 7/8/9.

Currently using IIS 7

**Final Result:**

In this case, the user can see a list of all disclosure PDFs that they have uploaded. The user can then click on one of the file names and the PDF will open up in a new tab / window.

In IE, Chrome, and Safari the path looks like this (Correct):

`http://localhost:1798/disclosures/bf1bb8bf-ef34-4c93-a4c3-540bab158644.pdf`

However, in Firefox it looks like this:

`http://localhost:1798/Disclosure\disclosures\bf1bb8bf-ef34-4c93-a4c3-540bab158644.pdf`

This is the URL of the current page:

`http://localhost:1798/Disclosure/Disclosures?lenderProductID=19&lenderID=64`

Why does it look like it is trying to combine the current URL with the virtual path? When I do click on one of the PDF links it opens a new tab / window but it reroutes me back to the index page.

Im not the best with IIS so any help would greatly be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is this displayed, where does the path come from in the first place? If it's in a HTML page, what does the HTML source code look like?

Comment: The list of PDFs is in a Telerik Grid. The following snoippet of code is what I am using to build the URL `.ClientTemplate("<a href='<#= FileLocation #><#= DisclosureFile #>' target='blank'><#= DisclosureName #></a>")`

Comment: Okay, but can you show the actual original data as it comes from the data source?

Comment: Im sorry, I guess I dont understand what you mean. Im working in a dev environment and I wouldnt be able to show you anything that would work. Are you referring to the actual PDF?

Comment: I mean, your problem is that URLs are getting garbled. Where do these URLs come from? The Telerik Grid shows them, but who *generates* them? What do they look like when you are querying your data source? I'm not sure how we can help you without that information. You are describing the symptom; you want to fix the *cause*.

Comment: We are creating the URLs by concatenating the 'FileLocation' which is grabbed from the Web.config and the 'DisclosureFile' which we already have from the db. Nothing is being generated for us. Sorry for not being clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for all the input. After looking in the web.config at the Image / File paths I noticed a silly mistake which turned out to be the source of my issue.

In the web.config I had back slashes in the string rather than forward slashes. I guess Chrome, IE, and Safari converted them properly but Firefox is a bit more strict in that regards.

Here are the two file paths that I found in the `<appSettings>`:

```
<add key="ImagePath" value="\images\" />
<add key="DisclosurePath" value="\disclosures\" />
```

However, they should look like this:

```
<add key="ImagePath" value="/images/" />
<add key="DisclosurePath" value="/disclosures/" />
```

Thanks to all! Now I can stop banging my head and put my Dunce cap on! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the URLs are rendered correctly?

My gut tells me that IE, Chrome and Safari are converting the backward slashes to forward slashes. FireFox is not doing this and that is why it appears to be broken in FireFox.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was thinking as well but when I scroll over the link in FF it displays the URL as `http://localhost:1798/Disclosure\disclosures\bf1bb8bf-ef34-4c93-a4c3-540bab158644.pdf`. Disclosures is in the URL twice.

Comment: @DzeimsasZvirblis it's also in the current page URL twice.

Comment: @DzeimsasZvirblis have you tried looking at the raw XML to see how it's rendered via a tool such as Fiddler or Firebug?

Comment: In the current URL `Disclosure`is the Controller and `Disclosures` is the the View. We dont have any XML in our solution to debug. We are thinking this may be more of a Telerik & Firefox issue.

Comment: @Dzeimsas I don't know Telerik's controls, but at some point data *has* to go from the server to the control. At some point, the link that you are clicking is being generated based on raw data coming from somewhere. That data you should look at.